# Use linux firewall rules for windows too

Tags: windows, linux, firewalls, automation

I'd like to improve security on my home network.
I have a PC and a laptop with Microsoft Windows as well as a PC and a laptop with Linux
There are a few HTTP services installed in the network. The devices should only be allowed access to DNS to router, HTTP and HTTPS to internet, and HTTP to certain local network devices.

I want to define the firewall rules just once and then roll them out programmatically.
Do you know of any good to that allows to configure firewall rules on Windows AND Linux?

Comment: This is both a "what product service does X?" question, and an administration question, not a security question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably a tool like [Firewall Builder](http://fwbuilder.sourceforge.net/)
that lets you design your rules once, then deploy to different platforms.

Note that the project on Sourceforge does not seem to be active/maintained anymore:

> After working on Firewall Builder for many years it is with some
>   sadness that Vadim and I are announcing that we have suspended all
>   development activity for this project. Firewall Builder has been a
>   great project to work on and we have truly appreciated all the support
>   and positive feedback that the user community has provided. Without
>   you we wouldn’t have been able to keep things going this long.

[Source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fwbuilder/)

But there seems to be a fork on Github: https://github.com/fwbuilder/fwbuilder.
I used FB a bit in the past but I have not evaluated recent versions.

Some people have mentioned Ferm or Capirca as possible alternatives. I can't advise on those packages.

Comment: I used it in the past, too but it doesn't support Windows, right?

Comment: Are you using the built-in Windows firewall ?

Comment: Yes, but I would consider an alternative 3rd party software